# Deriving the expected value of the sum of square residuals for linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, expected-value, residuals

I have a question regarding the following derivation (copied from page 11 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/lecture-15.pdf)) for $E[\hat\sigma^2]$ where $\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}e^Te$ is the sum of square residuals in linear regression. The notes define $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and $e=y-X\hat\beta=(I-H)y=(I-H)\epsilon$ if $Y = X\beta+\epsilon$ (in pages 1-2).

I think there's a typo from equation 31 and onwards, because I can't see how equation 30 and 34 can be equal. I think every $e$ from equations 31 to 35 should be replaced with $\epsilon$, then equation 36 would be $\frac{1}{n}tr((I-H)\sigma^2)$ (using the fact that $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2I)$) which gives the same result as equation 38. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: (30) and (34) are equal because $e$ is orthogonal to the column space of $X$. The argument looks OK to me.

Comment: @guy So the author is using the fact that $e=(I-H)y=(I-H)(I-H)y=(I-H)e$? This also happens to equal $(I-H)\epsilon$ if $y=X\beta + \epsilon$?